# Is UK transit visa required for an Iranian citizen holding a Canadian TRV?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, iranian-citizens

Does an Iranian passport holder (who has a Canadian Temporary Residence Visa, i.e., visitor visa) require a UK transit visa for the route below (Layover time is 3 hours and 55 minutes in London.)?

IKA-IST-LGW-YYC

Comment: Have you queried the UK Government's [Visa Wizard](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa)?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica: Yes, but it says it depends on the exiting (or remaining in) the transit saloon which I am not aware whether it is the case for my itinerary.

Comment: Putting your info into the Visa Wizard, I get [this page](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/iran/transit/somewhere_else), which says that you must have a visa if either a) you must leave the main airport building for any reason or you'll need to collect your bags and redeposit them for your connecting flight, or, in the alternative, b) if your onward flight leaves on a different calendar day and there's no hotel in the transit area. So: will your bags be previously checked through to YYC? Would you have to remain in the transit area until the next calendar day? Do those conditions apply?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity: Yes. DavidSupportsMonica's comment also solved the case.